Is there a way to create a migration that always runs in db-migrate, even if it has already been executed?
I'm using the db-migrate tool for managing database migrations in my project, and I need a way to ensure that a particular migration always runs, even if it has already been executed previously.
I know that db-migrate typically tracks which migrations have been applied using a migrations history table, and once a migration is marked as "executed," it won't be re-run. However, I need to force a migration to run every time, regardless of whether it has been executed in the past.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

updated question accordingly
